# How to override @Primary bean in spring boot JUnit test cases

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a Spring Boot application which has

- an interface: `EmailService`
- and it's implementation: `EmailServiceImpl` - This class is annotated with `@Primary`

```java
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@Service
@Primary
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    public void validateEmail(String email){
        // validation check
    }
}
```

I have another class `ResourceService` in which the above implementation is autowired.

```java
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@Service
public class ResourceService implements ResourceServiceInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;

    public boolean checkResource(String email, Long resourceId){
        emailService.validateEmail(email);
        // Code to check the resource
    }
}
```

I am trying to write JUnit test case for above `checkResource()` method in which I want to bypass the `emailService.validateEmail(email)` method.

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class JunitClass {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServiceInterface resource;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(emailService).validateEmail(Mockito.anyString());
        boolean validResource = resource.checkResource("email@gmail.com", 1234L);
        assertEquals(validResource, true);
    }
}
```

and the configuration class is:

```java
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class ServConf {
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EmailService getEmailService() {
        return Mockito.mock(EmailServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Of course this code does not work because Spring detects two beans annotated with `@Primary`.

What is the workaround to bypass the `emailService.validateEmail(email)` call during the JUnit test case run?

If I remove the `@Primary` from `EmailServiceImpl`, it will work for sure. But I am not supposed to modify the original code.

Comment: How about using a different profile for EmailServiceImpl? like @Profile("!test")

Comment: @Shawrup I am not supposed to modify the original code(Which is basically a product code). I was asked to write only junit test cases!

Comment: How about using `@MockBean private EmailService emailService; `  instead of autowiring, it should work.

Comment: I have read the documentation about @MockBean. Using that will solve my issue, but the application is written in spring boot-1.2.5.RELEASE. MockBean annotation is not supported. I have tried overriding spring-boot-starter-test version alone with 2.1.7.RELEASE(without changing the spring boot parent version as I am not supposed to change the application spring boot version which has many impacts). Now I am able to use MockBean, but on running the test case, it ends in exception.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getRepeatableAnnotations-@Shawrup.

Answer (score 4):

In your Test Config class add a name for bean as `MyEmailService` as follows:-

```java
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class ServConf {

     @Bean("MyEmailService")
     public EmailService getEmailService() {
        return Mockito.mock(EmailServiceImpl.class);
     }
}
```

And then in Test class add `@Qualifier("MyEmailService")` when autowiring the bean, the spring will then not pick the primary bean and will give you the mock bean. Details about [`@Qualifier`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation).

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = 
SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class JunitClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MyEmailService")
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServiceInterface resource;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(emailService).validateEmail(Mockito.anyString());
        boolean validResource = resource.checkResource("email@gmail.com", 1234L);
        assertEquals(validResource, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class JunitClass {


    private EmailService emailService = Mockito.mock(EmailService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServiceInterface resource;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(emailService).validateEmail(Mockito.anyString());
        boolean validResource = resource.checkResource("email@gmail.com", 1234L);
        assertEquals(validResource, true);
    }
}=
```